# Heart Beat Analysis

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am working on the analysis of heart beat sound, and I am not familiar with digital signal processing yet.

```
[x,fs]=audioread('C:\Users\Sheraz\Downloads\Music\mp3 Sound Effect_ heartbeat pulse slow.mp3');
    left=x(:,1);
    plot(left)
    v = fft(left);
    mag = abs(v);
    figure
    plot(mag)
```

The plot of the sound signal is:
[image]

And the plot of the magnitude of the fft of that signal is:
[image]

The plot of fft is weird i don't know why. And i am unable to extract something different like either is beating fast or slow etc.
Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: The FFT looks reasonable.  Read the MATLAB help for the function `fftshift`.

Comment: The FFT looks exactly as it should. I suggest you read a bit on what a fourier transform is, because you have the answer very close.The higher, the number in the FFT, the faster the signal is.

Comment: To extract the QRS-complex of the ECG I suggest the [Pan-Tompkins](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gari/teaching/cdt/A3/readings/ECG/Pan+Tompkins.pdf) algorithm. Matlab implementation [here](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45840-complete-pan-tompkins-implementation-ecg-qrs-detector)

Comment: Thanks a lot a gentlemen that was very helpful.